# EF Migration - Modify Existing Data during Migration w/ C# business logic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

As part of a migration I need to modify some existing data in a column, but this update must be transformed using C# code: Data must be read into C#, modified, then pushed back to the DB.

These changes must only happen once and only during this migration. (For that reason, conditionally applying this data update in the Seed method will not work, even if I inspect the MigrationHistory table, because more than one migration can be applied at a time, and this update cannot occur after a later migration.)

I'm unable to use plain ADO.NET during the migration because the `Up()` method merely builds up the operations that the framework will execute at a later time, and this modification relies on schema changes in the migration itself. (ie: the vanilla ADO.NET calls would happen prematurely.)

I feel like the most ideal way to achieve this would be a facility to conditionally inject our BL during the framework's actual script execution, but afaik this extensibility point is not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm unable to using plain ADO.NET during the migration because the Up() method merely builds up the operations that the framework will execute at a later time, and this modification relies on schema changes in the migration itself. (ie: the vanilla ADO.NET calls would happen prematurely.)

Create two migrations.

The first one performs the schema changes.

The second one starts out as an empty migration.  You edit the `Up()` method to execute all the C# code needed to modify the data.  Provide a matching `Down()` method if applicable.

Note that you *could* do all of this in a single migration by editing the first migration and placing your data transformation code at the end of the `Up()` method, and the reversal (if applicable) at the start of the `Down()` method.  I find separate migrations to be cleaner.

> These changes must only happen once and only during this migration

This is guaranteed by the mechanics of migrations.  Migrations are applied in order, and only migrations that have not been applied to the target database will run.

Comment: I tried doing it all in a single Migration, but the vanilla ADO.NET code was called *prior* to any of the schema modification before it in the `Up()` method. I thought about a second migration, but I'm mainly trying to avoid having 3 Migrations (need more modifications after the custom BL runs).

Comment: When I mention 'once & only during a particular migration' I meant that in the context of the `Seed()` method. Since I can't guarantee what version the DB will be in when it runs (ie: this can't be run after TargetMigration+3), I can't perform the modifications there.

Comment: We ended up just using a single migration and pushing off the schema changes until after. Some of the schema changes were to enable data recovery in the event bad transform was encountered, but we decided to forgo that as it's a very unlikely edge case (in this instance, anyway)

Comment: This idea sounds very good but it breaks if you change the model and try to create a new DB. More details here: https://jakejgordon.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/dont-reference-dbcontext-in-migrations/